# Mounting NFS directory causes creating Zero byte files

Tags: load-balancing, nfs, varnish, drupal

I have two Servers, Server X (IP 192.168.1.1) and Server Y (IP 192.168.1.2), both of them are ubuntu 9.1
i have created varnish load balancer on them for my drupal website (pressflow 6.22)
I have mounted a directory of imagecache from server X to Y as below

```
@X:/etc/exports ==> /var/www/proj/htdocs/sites/default/files/images   192.168.1.2(rw,async,no_subtree_check)

@Y:/etc/fstab ==> 192.168.1.1:/var/www/proj/htdocs/sites/default/files/images    var/www/proj/htdocs/sites/default/files/images   nfs defaults    0       0
```

also i made this on server X

```
X:/var/www/proj/htdocs/sites/default/files$ chmod -R 777 images
```

i tried to *touch, rm, vim, and cat>*  files in images directory that has been mounted on Y and everything went fine.
**now, *ALWAYS* when server Y's imagecache tries to create an image in images directory, the image is created with ZERO byte file size.**
anyone face the same before? any idea of how to fix this problem or what might cause it?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All,
i have found the problem.
i should install the following packages on server Y in order to get imagecahe working fine:

```
advpng  
optipng   
jpegtran  
jfifremove
```